# VS code disable IntelliSense types of completions

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable in vscode intellisense types of completions, not all type but how to leave only type I needed. For example I don not want (Methods, Functions and Constructors, Classes and so on)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to see the ones in red or are those the ones that should be hidden?

Comment: I want to hide in red, actually I want to know how can I handle it in settings

Comment: You should file an issue on the vscode github repo where you can directly get a response from the owners and contributors